# Java Memory Leaks on some environments

Tags: java, memory-leaks, java-8, garbage-collection

I have a Java app which when running on EC2 instances (jre 1.8.101) displays continuously growing memory usage and ultimately falls over when it reaches approx 900MB. The same application when running locally on MAC (jdk 1.8.77) also shows increasing memory but every now and then GC runs and I don't see the problem locally. Could this be because of GC not running for some reason on Linux boxes? How/what can I investigate further? Please provide me some clues.

Comment: by `fall over` you mean dies with an `OutOfMemory`?

Comment: Doesn't literally log OutOfMemory exception, but yes, the application dies and starts giving '502' error there after.

Comment: that an entirely different story... what is the settings of `-Xms` and `-Xmx` in your case? Reaching `900MB` might not be a problem at all.